# Custom like button IOS SDK

Tags: ios, swift, facebook-like, facebook-ios-sdk

it is possible to customize the facebook like button SDK? I need my turn Button image or set the background of the button as image

```
    var likeControl:FBSDKLikeControl = FBSDKLikeControl()
    likeControl.objectID = fbPage
    likeControl.likeControlStyle = FBSDKLikeControlStyle.BoxCount
    likeControl.backgroundColor = UIColor(patternImage: UIImage(named: "fblike")!)
    likeControl.frame = CGRectMake(16,20, 290, 40)
    self.viewBotoes.addSubview(likeControl)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You can't assign your own background image to the `FBSDKLikeControl`, which is inherited from the `UIControl`

`FBSDKLikeControl` is exposing only a few properties such as `foregroundColor`, `FBSDKLikeControlAuxiliaryPosition`, `FBSDKLikeControlHorizontalAlignment`, `likeControlStyle`, `preferredMaxLayoutWidth` and `soundEnabled`